# Parsing html pages in Haskell

Tags: html, parsing, haskell

I need to parse html pages. As far as I know BeautifulSoap is most popular library for parsing html pages in Python. How about Haskell? I found a few of them such as tagsoup, http-conduit and xml-conduit, [HXT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt)
And I'm hesitating which one to choose. Your suggestions?

Comment: You'd want to use html-conduit, not xml-conduit. The former can support non-well-formed documents, the latter is a strict XML parser.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman, even html-conduit itself uses xml-conduit.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Michael is creator of both packages =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HXT is very complex platform and needed for specific tasks. 
Very nice overview of HXT and its extension HandsomeSoup
http://adit.io/posts/2012-04-14-working_with_HTML_in_haskell.html

I prefer html-conduit, described here https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/text-manipulation/tagsoup

Comment: shouldn't I use xml-conduit as well? in https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/text-manipulation/tagsoup it is used.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp [html-conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/html-conduit) is part of xml-conduit and based on some of its features, you can use it as well.